# facebook add page tab using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I have been trying to find a way to add page tab in facebook using php sdk with no avail.

I have searched almost the entire google, stackoverfllow and facebook developer section.

don't even get me started with facebook developer section as it is the worst written documentation by human.(if its been written by human).

whatever else I found was basically using the URL in the browser like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=https://facebook.com
```

this is not what i want as that is the easy way.

I need to know, how I can use the `PHP SDK` to achieve the same result.

I have developed an app, I can also **manage_pages** using php sdk and I can get the users **page_id**. I can simply echo the `page_id` in an *inputfield* on my php page if the users allow the permission to manage pages.

Now, I need to know how I can use that selected page (page_id) within my php page to create/ADD PAGE TAB in that page.

could someone please point me in a right direction?

Thanks in advance.

I've also tried the following code which i though would work and all i get is blank page:

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';


$facebook->api('/I WILL PUT MY PAGE ID THERE/tabs', 'POST', array(
  'app_id'=>'MY APP ID GOES THERE',
  'access_token'=>'MY ACCESS TOKEN GOES THERE'
));
/* handle the result */

?>
```

EDIT:

this is the code taken from facebook developer section which does absolutely nothing:

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/236482648726347826/tabs',
  array (
    'app_id' => '64564564645645646456',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

}
?>
```

html PART:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index">
<input id="text" name="txtName">
</form>
```

isn't that suppose to bring up an ADD PAGE TAB dialog or in the worst case add the page tab behind the scene?

currently the code above produces a blank page after the form submit.

SECOND EDIT:

This is my full code:

**index.php code:**

```
    <?php
    include_once("config.php");
    if ($fbuser) {
      try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
            //Get user pages details using Facebook Query Language (FQL)
            $fql_query = 'SELECT page_id, name, page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid='.$fbuser.')';



            $postResults = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql_query));
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $fbuser = null;
      }
    }else{
            //Show login button for guest users
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
            echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/facebook-login.png" border="0"></a>';
            $fbuser = null;
    }

    if($fbuser && empty($postResults))
    {
            /*
            if user is logged in but FQL is not returning any pages, we need to make sure user does have a page
            OR "manage_pages" permissions isn't granted yet by the user. 
            Let's give user an option to grant application permission again.
            */
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
            echo '<br />Could not get your page details!';
            echo '<br /><a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Click here to try again!</a>'; 

    }elseif($fbuser && !empty($postResults)){

    //Everything looks good, show message form.
    ?>

    <?php

    //echo $access_token;

    if (isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

    $facebook->api('/MY PAGE ID/tabs', 'POST', array(
      'app_id'=>'MY APP ID',
      'access_token'=>$access_token
    ));


    }
    ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Post to user Page Wall</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="fbpagewrapper">
<div id="fbpageform" class="pageform">
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index">
<h1>Post to Facebook Page Wall</h1>
<p>Choose a page to post. <?php
/*
Get Log out URL
Due to some bug or whatever, SDK still thinks user is logged in even
after user logs out. To deal with it, user is redirected to another page "logged-out.php" after logout
it is working fine for me with this trick. Hope it works for you too.
*/
$logOutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>$homeurl.'logged-out.php'));
echo '<a href="'.$logOutUrl.'">Log Out</a>';
?>
</p>
<label>Pages
<span class="small">Select a Page</span>
</label>
<select name="userpages" id="upages">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
            echo '<option value="'.$postResult["page_id"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option>';
        }

    ?>
</select>

<input id="text" name="txtName">
<!--<label>Message
<span class="small">Write something to post!</span>
</label>
<textarea name="message"></textarea>-->
<button type="submit" class="button" id="submit_button">Send Message</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>


<script>
$('#upages').bind('change click keyup', function() {
  $('#text').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The config file:**

```
<?php
include_once("inc/facebook.php"); //include facebook SDK

######### edit details ##########
$appId = 'MY APP ID'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = 'MY APP SECRET NUMBER'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'https://MYDOMAIN.COM/';  //return url (url to script)
$homeurl = 'https://MYDOMIAN.COM';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';  //Required facebook permissions
##################################

//Call Facebook API
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appId,
  'secret' => $appSecret
));

$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
?>
```

As you can see, I get the access token in my config file like so:  `$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();`.

when i echo $access_token on my page after I got the manage pages permission from the user, i get a long number echoed on the page.

so, I tried to use the token like so:

```
<?php

//echo $access_token;

if (isset($_POST['txtName'])) {

$facebook->api('/MY PAGE ID/tabs', 'POST', array(
  'app_id'=>'MY APP ID',
  'access_token'=>$access_token
));


}
?>
```

but when i submit the form, I get no "Add Page Dialog" on my page.

that is my problem. now could someone please help me out as I am at total lost for the past 4 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/tabs/#publish you need to use a Page Access Token to do this.

You can get one by issueing a request to `/me/accounts` (with `manage_pages` permission) and using the respective Access Token for the Page in question.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts/#fields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/#columns

Comment: see, I have already stated that i get the page id and i can echo it in the inputfield. which means I need to get permission from the user to be able to do that and that also means that the access token has already been issued once the user allowed the permission.

Comment: Yes, I successfully read that! I wrote that you have to use the **Page Acess Token** to be able to do this, and not a User Access Token. I don't really understand where your problem is then? This is clearly stated in the docs I linked, and you already seem to have to Page ID and the appropriate permission. Like I wrote, you need to just get the Page Access Token via `/me/accounts` first!

Comment: I have been reading the facebook's documentation for about 3 days with no luck to understand any of it! whatever i've learnt so far was from my own trial and error or google search... facebook's documentation is not clear whatsoever. that's why i thought i might be able to get help from someone here who can speak human language and not facebook language. (no offence). P.S. i found that link that you posted about 2 days ago.

Comment: Well, I tried the exact same thing just before I posted my answer, and guess what: It works. Why you just don't try what I suggested is not clear to me, but ok. That's it from me.

Comment: try it how? If you look at my Edit in my question, you would see that I did try the exact same thing/code that was in the link you posted! I swear i get nothing! how did you test it? any chance you could share your tested code?

Comment: Where are you setting the Page Access Token? It's not in your code. You HAVE to set the Page Access Token you need to gather one step earlier as I described in my answer AND in my comments! I'm out.

Comment: am I talking african or something?!? I already said I am getting the token access 3 times! anyway, I'm out too as I can't be arsed to explain the simplest thing...

Comment: P.S delete your answer as it is irrelevant and I will need to delete this question.

Comment: Guys like you make it really hard here on SO sometimes... Learn how to ask questions, show enough (and relevant code) instead of insulting those who want to help you. Your edited code doesn't show anywhere that you set the Page Access Token for the request. So this plainly can't work like I said three times before. If you'd even have a look on the further links I added, you'd hopefully understand what is missing. But this seems to be too much to ask. Please go ahead and delete the question.

Comment: i understand that sometimes not showing enough code in the question could attract silly answers but I have explained it 3 times that i said that I am getting the MANAGE_PAGES permission and that's how I could echo their page's ID on my own php page. if you really want to help then Learn to read the question and understand it and then submit your answer accordingly.

Comment: It's not about the damn permission only!!! You need to use the Access Token in the `access_token` field in the result object of the `/me/accounts` request for the specific page, and use this in the second request (where you don't set any Access Token at all). How hard can this be?? It's all in the docs I linked. If you're not able to follow I guess it's not the other's fault. See, I'm not the one who needs help here.

Comment: I have posted my entire code now. I hope you'd understand the situation better. I feel like you are telling me to do something that i have already done but I could be barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: Yes, and it's exactly like I wrote several times: You're using an User Access Token instead of a Page Access Token. You're not even gathering one in your FQL code... And, also like the 5th time, the docs say that you can only add Page Tabs with a Page Access Token.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, see, that is the exact confusion that was having. I thought the page token and user token are the same thing.

Comment: If you'd read the docs I posted in my answer you could've know earlier. Whatever. Add the field `access_token` to the FQL request and use the result for your last call. And you need to store the Page Access Token in a PHP session or something similar, because otherwise you'll loose it because there's no field for it in your HTML form